# Automatic scatter plot in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have two quite large data sets of which I want to plot every line in one plot.
The pattern is the following:

x-axis: Set one (Colonne 1-6)
y-axis: Set two (Colonne 1-6)

Now I want such a plot for every line and hope there is a solution to generate them automatically since the Pattern stays the same.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Excel won't due this automatically, you'll need to either use VBA (is that acceptable), or hand enter each series (there are ways to quicken the process, but it's still repetitive. Or, if you don't need them all displayed simultaneously, you could easily have a dynamic chart that displays your series of interest.

Comment: Perhaps a Pivot Chart would work? Can you clarify the shape of your data?